# Collapsible or nested tasks using gulp in Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, gulp, webstorm

Is it possible to make collapsible or nested tasks in gulp? For example, my project has different modules that all can be built, rebuilt, watched, or served to the browser by themselves. As of now, a gulp task is made for each of these things which leads to a huge gulp list. It would be something like the following...

```
build:mod1
rebuild:mod1
watch:mod1
serve:mod1
build:mod2
rebuild:mod2
watch:mod2
serve:mod2
```

Is there a way to create a tree view which would have build, rebuild, watch, and serve all in the same level, and have a list of subtasks (mod1, mod2) under each of these?

```
[+] build
    -mod1
    -mod2

[+] rebuild
    -mod1
    -mod2

[+] watch
    -mod1
    -mod2

[+] serve
    -mod1
    -mod2
```

I know this is possible in grunt, so I'm assuming there is some type of way to do this in gulp as well.